# filter array doesn't work in React component

Tags: reactjs, filter

I wanna sort the sizes of my clothes but when I click to elect the size, no matter what I choose, it stays "All"...Is there anything wrong with my function `filterProducts`?

```
function Filter(props) {
  return (
    <div className="filter">
      <div className="filter-result">{props.count} Products</div>
      <div className="filter-sort">
        Order
        <select value={props.sort} onChange={props.sortProducts}>
          <option value="latest">Latest</option>
          <option value="lowest">Lowest</option>
          <option value="highest">Highest</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="filter-size">
        Filter
        <select value={props.size} onChange={props.filterProducts}>
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="">XS</option>
          <option value="">S</option>
          <option value="">M</option>
          <option value="">L</option>
          <option value="">XL</option>
          <option value="">XXL</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My codesand link:https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-tlpek?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the size options were missing unique `value` props, they were all `value=""`.

Update the `value` props to match your data:

```
Filter
<select value={props.size} onChange={props.filterProducts}>
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="XS">XS</option>
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
  <option value="XL">XL</option>
  <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
</select>
```

You also had a typo in `filterProducts` in `App` where you reset the state to a `product` property instead of `products`. This wasn't allowing the "All" filter value to work.

```
filterProducts = (event) => {
  if (event.target.value === "") { // all
    this.setState({
      size: event.target.value,
      products: data.products // <-- reset products!!
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      size: event.target.value,
      products: data.products.filter(
        (product) => product.availableSizes.indexOf(event.target.value) >= 0
      )
    });
  }
};
```